# x-editable-bootstrap select2 tags - loading indicator keeps spinning forever

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, x-editable

I'm using Meteor with the x-editable-bootstrap Meteorite (and bootstrap) package installed.

When I set up a select2 tags editable, the loading indicator keeps spinning forever, no tag input possible. Tried a lot, hope someone can help!

in my template I have a

```
<div id="editableStuff" data-title="Blah enter tags plz">Apple, Banana</div>
```

in my Template.rendered I hava a jQuery on-dom-ready function à la

```
$(function(){
  $('#editableStuff:not(.editable-click)').editable('destroy').editable({
    success: function(response, newValue) {
      Session.set('tmp'+name,newValue);
    },
    placement:'left',
    select2: {
      tags: ['cake', 'cookies'],
      tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
    },
    type:'select2'
  });
};
```

which creates the default element on the page with the dotted line. Clicking the element makes the x-editable popup window appear, but it does not load the input field, the loading indicator just keeps spinning.

The console logs the following error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.$input.select2(this.options.select2)')`

in `x-editable-bootstrap.js:3683`

I found out that when I remove the `type:'select2'` in the `editable({..})` the text field is loaded, but has no tag-functionality.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot for any hint! Other x-editable types like `address` and `text` work like a charm using the code patterns above!

Comment: Note that the above code no longer works on Meteor 0.8+. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23144211/586086

Comment: Reference for people like me, it may be the localization issue. Load select2.full and your problem may be solved..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried on meteor, but had the same issue on Rails. It turns out x-editable-bootstrap doesn't automatically come with select2.js. Make sure you are also loading select2.js

Answer (score 0):

You are missing select2.js. You can download select2 at here http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/