# How do I use X-editable on dynamic fields in a Meteor template now with Blaze?

Tags: meteor, x-editable, meteor-blaze

I had [x-editable](https://atmospherejs.com/package/x-editable-bootstrap3) working in Meteor 0.7.2 but since upgrading to 0.8.0 it no longer renders correctly. I tend to end up with a bunch of Empty tags. This is frustrating because the data is there, just not by the time the rendered function is fired.

```
<template name="clientPage">
    <header>{{> clientPageTitleUpdate}}</header>
</template>

<template name="clientPageTitleUpdate">
    <h1><span class="title-update editable" data-type="text" data-pk="{{_id}}" data-name="title" data-value="{{title}}">{{title}}</span></h1>
</template>


    Template.clientPageTitleUpdate.rendered = function() {

        console.log(this.$(".title-update").text());

        // set up inline as defaule for x-editable
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

        $(".title-update.editable:not(.editable-click)").editable('destroy').editable({

            url:    "empty",
            toggle: "dblclick",

            success: function (response, newValue) {
                // update value in db
                var currentClientId = $(this).data("pk");
                var clientProperties = { title: newValue };

                Clients.update(currentClientId, {$set: clientProperties}, function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                        Errors.throw(error.message)
                    }
                });
            }// success

        });

    }
```

I have tried the "new" rendered method of embeding the this into another template as explained [here](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes) and it doesn't seem to work either.

What is the best way to use x-editable now that rendered only fires once and doesn't make sure the data is there.

I am using Iron Router and my templates are not embeded in an {{#each}} block which seems to be the basic solution to the new rendered model.

This question is related to this older topic about [x-editable in a meteor template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992791/how-do-i-use-x-editable-on-dynamic-fields-in-a-meteor-template/22867492#22867492).

Any help whatsoever would be super appreciated here. I am at a loss. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: Much easier to implement now in Meteor 0.8.3**:

Template:

```
<template name="docTitle">
    <span class="editable" title="Rename this document" data-autotext="never">{{this}}</span>
</template>
```

Code:

```
Template.docTitle.rendered = ->
  tmplInst = this

  this.autorun ->
    # Trigger this whenever data source changes
    Blaze.getCurrentData()

    # Destroy old editable if it exists
    tmplInst.$(".editable").editable("destroy").editable
      display: ->
      success: (response, newValue) -> # do stuff
```

For this to be most efficient, make sure the data context of the editable template is only the field being edited, as in the example above with `{{> docTitle someHelper}}`.

---

**Outdated information follows for Meteor 0.8.0 to 0.8.2**

I also had to do this but wasn't sure about using the global helper in my app. So I tried to accomplish it by just changing the behavior of the editable.

The main things that needed to be done, after [perusing the docs](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable-options) and source, were:

- Set the value of the form from the field text
- Override the `display` function so that [reactivity of text updated by Meteor doesn't break](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1990)
- Make sure the above two functions don't break

Here's the code (apologies for Coffeescript):

```coffee
Template.foo.rendered = ->
  container = @$('div.editable')
  settings =
    # When opening the popover, get the value from text
    value: -> $.trim container.text()
    # Don't set innerText ourselves, let Meteor update to preserve reactivity
    display: ->
    success: (response, newValue) =>
      FooCollection.update @data._id,
        $set: { field: newValue }
      # Reconstruct the editable so it shows the correct form value next time
      container.editable('destroy').editable(settings)
  container.editable(settings)
```

This is ugly because it destroys and re-creates the popover after setting a new value, so that the form field updates from the correct value.

After some more reverse engineering, I found a cleaner way to do this that doesn't involve destroying the editable. Gadi was right on that `container.data().editableContainer.formOptions.value` has something to do with it. It's because this value is [set after the update](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/blob/f32802f48a33b8a7ec9cca32eec4ca844b7d39b2/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js#L271) because x-editable thinks it can cache this now. Well, it can't, so we replace this with the original function so the value continues being updated from the text field.

```coffee
Template.tsAdminBatchEditDesc.rendered = ->
  container = @$('div.editable')
  grabValue = -> $.trim container.text() # Always get reactively updated value
  container.editable
    value: grabValue
    display: -> # Never set text; have Meteor update to preserve reactivity
    success: (response, newValue) =>
      Batches.update @data._id,
        $set: { desc: newValue }
      # Thinks it knows the value, but it actually doesn't - grab a fresh value each time
      Meteor.defer -> container.data('editableContainer').formOptions.value = grabValue
```

Notes:

- `$.trim` above was taken from [the default behavior to render value](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/blob/f32802f48a33b8a7ec9cca32eec4ca844b7d39b2/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js#L1505)
- For more discussion about this see https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-x-editable-bootstrap/issues/15
- This is all an ugly hack, hopefully in the future we'll see better support for two-way variable bindings in Meteor.

I will try to make this more concise in the future pending better support from Meteor for depending on data reactively.

Comment: was just taking another look at this; if you have two windows open, update window1, and then click on x-editable in window2, is the value that appears in the x-editable popup correct?

i think if you lose the global helper (which I also don't like), you'll still need to do a deps.autorun somewhere to update x-editable's internal data when the value is reactively updated.

Comment: @gadicc much easier now in 0.8.3

Comment: thanks for the heads up!  Is there a reason you went back to destroying and recreating the xeditable instance rather than updating the info?

Comment: Yes, because it's much cleaner and doesn't depend on monkey patching x-editable.

Comment: What does "= - >" or "- >" mean? Is this part of blaze or spacebar syntax?

Comment: It's just `function() { ... }` in CoffeeScript syntax. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated for Meteor 0.8.3+**

This covered all cases for me (see below the code).  This uses pretty fine-grained reactivity and will update the x-editable instance only when the specified value changes.

**Template:**

```html
<!-- once off for your entire project -->
<template name="xedit">
    {{> UI.contentBlock}}
</template>

<!-- per instance -->
<template name="userInfo">
  {{#xedit value=profile.name}}<a>{{profile.name}}</a>{{/xedit}}
</template>
```

**Client Javascript (for Meteor 0.8.3+):**

```js
// once off for your entire project
Template.xedit.rendered = function() {
  var container = this.$('*').eq(0);
  this.autorun(function() {
    var value = Blaze.getCurrentData().value;
    var elData = container.data();
    if (elData && elData.editable) {
      elData.editable.setValue(value, true);
      // no idea why this is necessary; xeditable bug?
      if (elData.editableContainer)
        elData.editableContainer.formOptions.value = elData.editable.value;
    }
  });
}

// per instance; change selector as necessary
Template.userInfo.rendered = function() {
  // Note you don't need all the :not(.editable) stuff in Blaze
  this.$('a').editable({
    success: function(response, newValue) {
      // according to your needs
      var docId = $(this).closest('[data-user-id]').attr('data-user-id');
      var query = { $set: {} }; query['$set']['profile.username'] = newValue;
      Meteor.users.update(docId, query);
    }
  });
});
```

You can see it in action at http://doingthiswithmeteor.com/ (with two windows open).  You need to be logged in, but try change any of your info on the "me" page.

1. Setup x-editable in rendered() as usual
2. Ability for custom display functions, "empty" values, etc.
3. Open in two windows.  Change value in win1, click on value in win2.. the POPUP should display the correct value.
4. Support for custom types like dates and arrays from custom helpers

Just implemented this... still doing some testing but feedback welcome.  This replaces my previous helper workaround.

Comment: thanks, integrated that into a better/updated approach.

Comment: I get "Blaze.getCurrentData is not a function" :(

Answer (score 1):

If Andrew's answer worked for you, and you have a lot of fields like this, you may find convenient to use a function to create the required templates. Here is an example

```
<template name="main">
  <div style="height:200px"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      {{#each editables}}
        {{> editable1}}
        {{> editable2}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="editable1">
  <p id="{{id}}" data-type="textarea" data-placeholder="Enter text" data-emptytext="Click to enter text" data-rows="4">{{content}}</p>
</template>
<template name="editable2">
  <p id="{{id}}" data-type="textarea" data-placeholder="Enter text" data-emptytext="Click to enter text" data-rows="4">{{content}}</p>
</template>
```

and in the js:

```
Template.main.editables = function(){
  return Objects.find({});
};

function xeditFactory(collection, template, field){
  template.content = function(){ return this[field]; };
  template.id      = function(){ return 'xedit_'+this._id+'_'+field; };
  template.rendered = function(){
    var container = this.$('#xedit_'+this.data._id+'_'+field);
    console.log(container);
    var grabValue = function() {
      return $.trim(container.text());
    };
    return container.editable({
      value: grabValue,
      display: function() {},
      success: (function(_this) {
        return function(response, newValue) {
          var set = {};
          set[field]=newValue;
          collection.update(_this.data._id, {$set:set});
          return Meteor.defer(function() {
            return container.data('editableContainer').formOptions.value = grabValue;
          });
        };
      })(this)
    });
  };
}

xeditFactory(Objects, Template.editable1, 'field1');
xeditFactory(Objects, Template.editable2, 'field2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another implementation working with iron-router and managing Collection2 validation:

The control

```
div(id="text" class="editable" data-type="text" data-pk="#{_id}" data-name="address" data-value="#{address}" data-context="Buildings") #{address}
```

And the JS code:

```
  setTimeout( ->   #needed to work with iron-router
    $(".editable").editable
      placement: "auto top"
      display: ->
      success: (response, newValue) ->
        newVal = {}
        oldVal = $.trim $(this).data("value")
        name = $(this).data("name")
        newVal[name] = newValue
        eval($(this).data("context")).update $(this).data("pk"), $set: newVal
        , (error) ->
          Notifications.error error.message
          Meteor.defer -> $(".editable[data-name=" + name + "]").data('editableContainer').formOptions.value = oldVal

        console.log "set new value to " + newValue
        Session.set "text", newValue
  ,500)
```

I couldn't find a way to set the data context automatically. I'm sure it shouldn't be very difficult. Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Working off of Andrew's answer, I was able to get this to work for me. It's not in coffeescript, also I think the Blaze.getCurrentData() might now be Blaze.getData() as per the Meteor docs.

Template:

```
<template name="objective">
    <p id="objective" class="editable" data-type="textarea" data-placeholder="Enter text" data-emptytext="Click to enter text" data-rows="4">{{objective.value}}</p>
</template>
```

Code:

```
Template.objective.rendered = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.autorun(function(){
        data = Blaze.getData();
        self.$("#objective.editable").editable("destroy").editable({
            placement: "bottom",
            display: function(){},
            success: function(response, newValue){
                var insert = {
                    "contract_id":data._id,
                    "value": newValue
                };
                Meteor.call('update_objective', insert);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

There are probably improvements I can make and I'm happy to hear them, but I spent a lot of time dealing with bad coffeescript translation (kept telling me to use return all the time), so I wanted to add another example.

Answer (score 0):

This is my simplified approach, based on gadicc's post (tested with Meteor 0.9.3).

Let's say there is a `MyDocuments` collection, which is rendered via `documentList` template. Each document in the collection has the `title` field, which we want to edit using xedtiable.

**document.html**

```html
<template name="documentList">
    {{#each documents}}
        {{>document}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="document">
   <p>Title: {{>xeditable titleOptions}}</p>
</document>
```

**document.js**

```js
Template.document.titleOptions = function () {
    return {
        // We need to specify collection, id and field to autoupdate MongoDb
        collection: MyDocuments,
        id: this._id,
        field: 'title',
        value: this.title             
    }
}
```

**xeditable.html**

```js
<template name="xeditable">
    <span class="xeditable">{{value}}</span>
</template>
```

**xeditable.js**

```js
Template.xeditable.rendered = function () {
    var container = this.$('*').eq(0);
    if (!container.hasClass('processed')) {
        container.addClass('processed');
        var options = _.extend(this.data, {
            // Default success function, saves document do database
            success: function (response, value) {
                var options = $(this).data().editable.options;
                if (options.collection && options.id && options.field) {
                    var update = {};
                    update[options.field] = value;
                    options.collection.update(options.id, {
                        $set: update
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        container.editable(options);
    }

    this.autorun(function () {
        var value = Blaze.getData().value;
        var elData = container.data();
        if (elData && elData.editable) {
            elData.editable.setValue(value, true);
            // no idea why this is necessary; xeditable bug?
            if (elData.editableContainer)
                elData.editableContainer.formOptions.value = elData.editable.value;
        }
    });
}
```